# Conditionally enabling HTML5 Application Cache ("installing" a web app)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-appcache

When using a web app with a `<html manifest="foo.manifest">` tag, then Chrome automatically loads the manifest into the cache.

Firefox however blocks the application cache events until the user has clicked on the top bar which asks "do you want to allow xyz.com to store data for offline use?".

Now, my single-page-application waits upon the application cache events to initiate page load - so a Chrome user experiences normal application behaviour, but a Firefox user has to confirm the "install" before the white screen gets content (and I don't have a way to tell this to the user!).

Now I'd remove the manifest attribute from index.php and provide a "install" option in the application settings which'd redirect the user to "index.php?enableManifest" (and the server would output the manifest attribute again).

This, however, is suboptimal as the user has to select the ?enableManifest URL in the navigation bar and change potential bookmarks. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Why do you wait on the application cache events before initializing the app?

Comment: Because I need four AJAX requests to fetch resources (login, feed lists, user preferences) and it's a huge waste on bandwidth and latency if the Application Manifest Update event fires after the requests have completed (and so the application has to be reloaded => the AJAX requests are wasted).

Comment: I don't know by heart: Does Firefox fire an appcache "checking" event even if the user has not approved offline functionality yet? Assuming it does not, you could set a timeout to wait for the appcache "checking" event. If the checking event does not come soon enough, remove the listener you'd otherwise use and initialize the app straight away.